# Spakers hardware problem or software?

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, soundcard, speakers

A few days ago I had my Dell Vostro laptop opened up and checked for charging port issue. I'm afraid that during that process something might have disturbed the speakers connectors or wires. Although, in my knowledge the speakers were unaffected. Since, then my speakers are not working. System diagnostics and Ubuntu show that the speakers are working fine even though I'm not hearing any sound from them even at full volume. My external bluetooth speakers are working fine when connected. How can I be sure that this is not a software problem? If it is, then I might be able to fix it myself at home. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The only way to know if it's a hardware problem - in relation to the fact your system had been serviced - is to open up the computer and check all your wire connections from speakers to the system mainboard.  If you had the system opened up and worked on, it's possible one of the small wires or connections did not properly stay in place (this happened to me once long agon in the past) and as such needed to be reconnected.  However, there's no way to determine if this is a hardware or software problem simply within Ubuntu.

Comment: If you plug in some headphones and hear the sound, pulse/pipewire seem to work and you should consider a connection failure. The service might've disturbed the wiring - follow the wires and apply a little bit of "Contact spray" at the connectors - works for me in over 80% of the cases encountered...

Comment: I'd try a live USB session - if the speakers work in a live session then obviously they work ... if not, then it's likely hardware as you've excluded your Ubuntu OS.

Comment: @ThomasWard and kanehekilli your advices worked. You guys are lifesaver. Motivated me to fix it myself.